# Photoshop free transform with CSS

Tags: css, rotation, transform, photoshop

I'm tring to transform a div like this picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGRSq.png

Original image is this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKj8w.png

I need something like this:

```
transform: rotate3d(x,x,x,xdeg) skew(x)
```

or any algorithm calculates that degrees.

Edit: Demo: codepen.io/yy/pen/zGZdXg (Fitting the ".grid" div to the ipad's screen)

Thank you

Comment: please refer this it may help full to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126731/div-with-irregular-shapes-with-css3-and-html5

Comment: Thanks @KarthiKeyan, but I'm trying to fit a div to an ipad screen. Thus I need exact degrees or an algorithm that can give me that.

Answer (score 1):

One of my friends, Cihad Turhan, solved and created this beauty:

codepen.io/cihadturhan/pen/RPpxOK/

```js
function adj(m) { // Compute the adjugate of m
  return [
    m[4]*m[8]-m[5]*m[7], m[2]*m[7]-m[1]*m[8], m[1]*m[5]-m[2]*m[4],
    m[5]*m[6]-m[3]*m[8], m[0]*m[8]-m[2]*m[6], m[2]*m[3]-m[0]*m[5],
    m[3]*m[7]-m[4]*m[6], m[1]*m[6]-m[0]*m[7], m[0]*m[4]-m[1]*m[3]
  ];
}
function multmm(a, b) { // multiply two matrices
  var c = Array(9);
  for (var i = 0; i != 3; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j != 3; ++j) {
      var cij = 0;
      for (var k = 0; k != 3; ++k) {
        cij += a[3*i + k]*b[3*k + j];
      }
      c[3*i + j] = cij;
    }
  }
  return c;
}
function multmv(m, v) { // multiply matrix and vector
  return [
    m[0]*v[0] + m[1]*v[1] + m[2]*v[2],
    m[3]*v[0] + m[4]*v[1] + m[5]*v[2],
    m[6]*v[0] + m[7]*v[1] + m[8]*v[2]
  ];
}
function pdbg(m, v) {
  var r = multmv(m, v);
  return r + " (" + r[0]/r[2] + ", " + r[1]/r[2] + ")";
}
function basisToPoints(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4) {
  var m = [
    x1, x2, x3,
    y1, y2, y3,
     1,  1,  1
  ];
  var v = multmv(adj(m), [x4, y4, 1]);
  return multmm(m, [
    v[0], 0, 0,
    0, v[1], 0,
    0, 0, v[2]
  ]);
}
function general2DProjection(
  x1s, y1s, x1d, y1d,
  x2s, y2s, x2d, y2d,
  x3s, y3s, x3d, y3d,
  x4s, y4s, x4d, y4d
) {
  var s = basisToPoints(x1s, y1s, x2s, y2s, x3s, y3s, x4s, y4s);
  var d = basisToPoints(x1d, y1d, x2d, y2d, x3d, y3d, x4d, y4d);
  return multmm(d, adj(s));
}
function project(m, x, y) {
  var v = multmv(m, [x, y, 1]);
  return [v[0]/v[2], v[1]/v[2]];
}
function transform2d(elt, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4) {
  var w = elt.offsetWidth, h = elt.offsetHeight;
  var t = general2DProjection
    (0, 0, x1, y1, w, 0, x2, y2, 0, h, x3, y3, w, h, x4, y4);
  for(i = 0; i != 9; ++i) t[i] = t[i]/t[8];
  t = [t[0], t[3], 0, t[6],
       t[1], t[4], 0, t[7],
       0   , 0   , 1, 0   ,
       t[2], t[5], 0, t[8]];
  t = "matrix3d(" + t.join(", ") + ")";
  elt.style["-webkit-transform"] = t;
  elt.style["-moz-transform"] = t;
  elt.style["-o-transform"] = t;
  elt.style.transform = t;
}

corners = [0, 0, 600, 0, 0, 800, 600, 800];
function update() {
  var box = document.getElementById("box");
  transform2d(box, corners[0], corners[1], corners[2], corners[3],
                   corners[4], corners[5], corners[6], corners[7]);
  for (var i = 0; i != 8; i += 2) {
    var elt = document.getElementById("marker" + i);
    elt.style.left = corners[i] + "px";
    elt.style.top = corners[i + 1] + "px";
  }
}
function move(evnt) {
  if (currentcorner < 0) return;
  corners[currentcorner] = evnt.pageX;
  corners[currentcorner + 1] = evnt.pageY;
  update();
}
currentcorner = -1;
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.documentElement.style.margin="0px";
  document.documentElement.style.padding="0px";
  document.body.style.margin="0px";
  document.body.style.padding="0px";
  update();
});
window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evnt) {
  var x = evnt.pageX, y = evnt.pageY, dx, dy;
  var best = 400; // 20px grab radius
  currentcorner = -1;
  for (var i = 0; i != 8; i += 2) {
    dx = x - corners[i];
    dy = y - corners[i + 1];
    if (best > dx*dx + dy*dy) {
      best = dx*dx + dy*dy;
      currentcorner = i;
    }
  }
  move(evnt);
});
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(evnt) {
  currentcorner = -1;
})
window.addEventListener('mousemove', move);
```

```css
*{
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
#container {
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: clip;
}
#box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 1600px;
  height: 2133.3333px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.corner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px; left: 0px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}




body {
  background: #65a8e7;
}
.ipad-animation {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 0%; left: 0%;
  
 /*-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
}
 .ipad-animation .base {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
 }
  .ipad-animation .base img {
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   width: 700px;
  }
 .ipad-animation .grid {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 600px;
    height: 800px;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #f7ae28;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
  .ipad-animation .column {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   width: 400px;
  }
  .ipad-animation .item {
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   margin: 0 10px 22px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: #fff;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.16);
   border-radius: 4px;
   white-space: normal;

   /*visibility: hidden;
   pointer-events: none;
   opacity: 0;*/
  }
  .ipad-animation .item.active {
   visibility: visible;
   pointer-events: all;
   opacity: 1;
  }
   .ipad-animation .item-image {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%; height: auto;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
   }
   .ipad-animation .item-author {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 17px 20px;
   }
    .ipad-animation .author-image {
     position: relative;
     display: block;
     float: left;
     width: 56px; height: 56px;
     margin-right: 10px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     vertical-align: middle;
    }
     .ipad-animation .author-image img {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      border-radius: 50%;
     }
    .ipad-animation .author-name {
     position: relative;
     display: block;
     width: calc(100% - 66px);
     padding-top: 10px;
     font-size: 21px;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #1a1a1a;
    }
    .ipad-animation .item-info {
     position: relative;
     display: block;
     width: calc(100% - 66px);
     padding-bottom: 5px;
     font-size: 10px;
     font-weight: 400;
     color: #999;
    }
     .ipad-animation .item-source {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 18px; height: 18px;
      margin-right: 3px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      font-size: 10px;
      color: #fff;
      line-height: 18px;
      text-align: center;
      background: #ccc;
     }
     .ipad-animation .item-source.fs-facebook  {background: #3b5998}
     .ipad-animation .item-source.fs-twitter   {background: #55acee}
     .ipad-animation .item-source.fs-swarm     {background: #ff9d0f}
     .ipad-animation .item-source.fs-pinterest {background: #cc2127}
     .ipad-animation .item-source.fs-instagram {background: #3f729b}
     .ipad-animation .item-source.fs-vine      {background: #00b488}
     .ipad-animation .item-source.fs-youtube   {background: #cd201f}
      .ipad-animation .item-source:before {
       display: block;
       line-height: 18px;
      }
     .ipad-animation .item-date {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
      line-height: 20px;
     }
    .ipad-animation .item-content {
     position: relative;
     display: block;
     padding: 0 20px 20px;
     font-size: 16px;
     font-weight: 400;
     line-height: 22px;
     color: #3b3b3b;
    }
     .ipad-animation .item-content a {
      font-weight: 600;
      color: #65a8e7;
      -ms-word-break: break-all;
      word-break: break-all;
     }
```

```html
<div class="ipad-animation" id="container">
  <div class="base">
    <img src="http://flat.social/site-assets/images/ipad_gold.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid" id="box">
    <div id="marker0" class="corner">TL</div>
<div id="marker2" class="corner">TR</div>
<div id="marker4" class="corner">BL</div>
<div id="marker6" class="corner">BR</div>
    <div class="column size-1of4">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/270/nature/1" alt="" class="item-image">
        <div class="item-author">
          <span class="author-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/1" alt=""></span>
          <span class="author-name">Jenny Yelriwer</span>
          <span class="item-info">
            <i class="item-source fs-instagram"></i>
            <span class="item-date">30 min</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere nibh vel efficitur luctus. Cras consectetur commodo felis, eu blandit augue tincidunt id.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/270/nature/2" alt="" class="item-image">
        <div class="item-author">
          <span class="author-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/2" alt=""></span>
          <span class="author-name">Jenny Yelriwer</span>
          <span class="item-info">
            <i class="item-source fs-twitter"></i>
            <span class="item-date">30 min</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere nibh vel efficitur luctus. Cras consectetur commodo felis, eu blandit augue tincidunt id.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-author">
          <span class="author-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/3" alt=""></span>
          <span class="author-name">Jenny Yelriwer</span>
          <span class="item-info">
            <i class="item-source fs-facebook"></i>
            <span class="item-date">30 min</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere nibh vel efficitur luctus. Cras consectetur commodo felis, eu blandit augue tincidunt id.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-author">
          <span class="author-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/4" alt=""></span>
          <span class="author-name">Jenny Yelriwer</span>
          <span class="item-info">
            <i class="item-source fs-facebook"></i>
            <span class="item-date">30 min</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere nibh vel efficitur luctus. Cras consectetur commodo felis, eu blandit augue tincidunt id.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/270/nature/1" alt="" class="item-image">
        <div class="item-author">
          <span class="author-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/1" alt=""></span>
          <span class="author-name">Jenny Yelriwer</span>
          <span class="item-info">
            <i class="item-source fs-instagram"></i>
            <span class="item-date">30 min</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere nibh vel efficitur luctus. Cras consectetur commodo felis, eu blandit augue tincidunt id.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/270/nature/2" alt="" class="item-image">
        <div class="item-author">
          <span class="author-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/2" alt=""></span>
          <span class="author-name">Jenny Yelriwer</span>
          <span class="item-info">
            <i class="item-source fs-twitter"></i>
            <span class="item-date">30 min</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere nibh vel efficitur luctus. Cras consectetur commodo felis, eu blandit augue tincidunt id.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column size-1of4">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/270/nature/3" alt="" class="item-image">
        <div class="item-author">
          <span class="author-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/2" alt=""></span>
          <span class="author-name">Jenny Yelriwer</span>
          <span class="item-info">
            <i class="item-source fs-twitter"></i>
            <span class="item-date">30 min</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere nibh vel efficitur luctus. Cras consectetur commodo felis, eu blandit augue tincidunt id.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-author">
          <span class="author-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/4" alt=""></span>
          <span class="author-name">Jenny Yelriwer</span>
          <span class="item-info">
            <i class="item-source fs-facebook"></i>
            <span class="item-date">30 min</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere nibh vel efficitur luctus. Cras consectetur commodo felis, eu blandit augue tincidunt id.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/270/nature/4" alt="" class="item-image">
        <div class="item-author">
          <span class="author-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/2" alt=""></span>
          <span class="author-name">Jenny Yelriwer</span>
          <span class="item-info">
            <i class="item-source fs-twitter"></i>
            <span class="item-date">30 min</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere nibh vel efficitur luctus. Cras consectetur commodo felis, eu blandit augue tincidunt id.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-author">
          <span class="author-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/3" alt=""></span>
          <span class="author-name">Jenny Yelriwer</span>
          <span class="item-info">
            <i class="item-source fs-facebook"></i>
            <span class="item-date">30 min</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere nibh vel efficitur luctus. Cras consectetur commodo felis, eu blandit augue tincidunt id.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/270/nature/3" alt="" class="item-image">
        <div class="item-author">
          <span class="author-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/2" alt=""></span>
          <span class="author-name">Jenny Yelriwer</span>
          <span class="item-info">
            <i class="item-source fs-twitter"></i>
            <span class="item-date">30 min</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere nibh vel efficitur luctus. Cras consectetur commodo felis, eu blandit augue tincidunt id.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-author">
          <span class="author-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/4" alt=""></span>
          <span class="author-name">Jenny Yelriwer</span>
          <span class="item-info">
            <i class="item-source fs-facebook"></i>
            <span class="item-date">30 min</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere nibh vel efficitur luctus. Cras consectetur commodo felis, eu blandit augue tincidunt id.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column size-1of4">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-author">
          <span class="author-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/4" alt=""></span>
          <span class="author-name">Jenny Yelriwer</span>
          <span class="item-info">
            <i class="item-source fs-facebook"></i>
            <span class="item-date">30 min</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere nibh vel efficitur luctus. Cras consectetur commodo felis, eu blandit augue tincidunt id.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/270/nature/5" alt="" class="item-image">
        <div class="item-author">
          <span class="author-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/3" alt=""></span>
          <span class="author-name">Jenny Yelriwer</span>
          <span class="item-info">
            <i class="item-source fs-facebook"></i>
            <span class="item-date">30 min</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere nibh vel efficitur luctus. Cras consectetur commodo felis, eu blandit augue tincidunt id.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-author">
          <span class="author-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/4" alt=""></span>
          <span class="author-name">Jenny Yelriwer</span>
          <span class="item-info">
            <i class="item-source fs-facebook"></i>
            <span class="item-date">30 min</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere nibh vel efficitur luctus. Cras consectetur commodo felis, eu blandit augue tincidunt id.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/270/nature/6" alt="" class="item-image">
        <div class="item-author">
          <span class="author-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/2" alt=""></span>
          <span class="author-name">Jenny Yelriwer</span>
          <span class="item-info">
            <i class="item-source fs-twitter"></i>
            <span class="item-date">30 min</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere nibh vel efficitur luctus. Cras consectetur commodo felis, eu blandit augue tincidunt id.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-author">
          <span class="author-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/4" alt=""></span>
          <span class="author-name">Jenny Yelriwer</span>
          <span class="item-info">
            <i class="item-source fs-facebook"></i>
            <span class="item-date">30 min</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere nibh vel efficitur luctus. Cras consectetur commodo felis, eu blandit augue tincidunt id.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/270/nature/5" alt="" class="item-image">
        <div class="item-author">
          <span class="author-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/3" alt=""></span>
          <span class="author-name">Jenny Yelriwer</span>
          <span class="item-info">
            <i class="item-source fs-facebook"></i>
            <span class="item-date">30 min</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere nibh vel efficitur luctus. Cras consectetur commodo felis, eu blandit augue tincidunt id.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column size-1of4">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-author">
          <span class="author-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/4" alt=""></span>
          <span class="author-name">Jenny Yelriwer</span>
          <span class="item-info">
            <i class="item-source fs-facebook"></i>
            <span class="item-date">30 min</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere nibh vel efficitur luctus. Cras consectetur commodo felis, eu blandit augue tincidunt id.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-author">
          <span class="author-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/4" alt=""></span>
          <span class="author-name">Jenny Yelriwer</span>
          <span class="item-info">
            <i class="item-source fs-facebook"></i>
            <span class="item-date">30 min</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere nibh vel efficitur luctus. Cras consectetur commodo felis, eu blandit augue tincidunt id.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/270/nature/7" alt="" class="item-image">
        <div class="item-author">
          <span class="author-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/2" alt=""></span>
          <span class="author-name">Jenny Yelriwer</span>
          <span class="item-info">
            <i class="item-source fs-twitter"></i>
            <span class="item-date">30 min</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere nibh vel efficitur luctus. Cras consectetur commodo felis, eu blandit augue tincidunt id.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/270/nature/8" alt="" class="item-image">
        <div class="item-author">
          <span class="author-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/4" alt=""></span>
          <span class="author-name">Jenny Yelriwer</span>
          <span class="item-info">
            <i class="item-source fs-facebook"></i>
            <span class="item-date">30 min</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere nibh vel efficitur luctus. Cras consectetur commodo felis, eu blandit augue tincidunt id.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-author">
          <span class="author-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/4" alt=""></span>
          <span class="author-name">Jenny Yelriwer</span>
          <span class="item-info">
            <i class="item-source fs-facebook"></i>
            <span class="item-date">30 min</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere nibh vel efficitur luctus. Cras consectetur commodo felis, eu blandit augue tincidunt id.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="item-author">
          <span class="author-image"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/4" alt=""></span>
          <span class="author-name">Jenny Yelriwer</span>
          <span class="item-info">
            <i class="item-source fs-facebook"></i>
            <span class="item-date">30 min</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere nibh vel efficitur luctus. Cras consectetur commodo felis, eu blandit augue tincidunt id.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ghosts"></div>
</div>


<!-- <div id="container">
<div id="box">
<p>This is a test.</p>
<p>Move the corners of this div using your mouse.</p>
</div>
<div id="marker0" class="corner">TL</div>
<div id="marker2" class="corner">TR</div>
<div id="marker4" class="corner">BL</div>
<div id="marker6" class="corner">BR</div>
</div> -->
```

Thank you